# Export data from Oracle Database 12c using Python 2.7

Tags: python, sql, oracle, python-2.7, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export a table, contained within an Oracle 12c database, to csv format - using Python 2.7. The code I have written is shown below:

```
import os
import cx_Oracle
import csv

SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ORACLE_TABLE'
filename = 'C:\Temp\Python\Output.csv'
file = open(filename, 'w')
output = csv.writer(file, dialect='excel')

connection = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@connection_name')

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(SQL)

for i in cursor:
    output.writerow(i)

cursor.close()
connection.close()
file.close()
```

This code yields an error in the line where I define 'connection':

**ORA-12557: TNS:protocol adapter not loadable**

How can I remedy this? Any help would be appreciated.

**Please note:** I have already encountered StackOverflow responses to very similar problems to this. However, they often suggest changing the path within environment variables - **I cannot do this since I don't have appropriate administer privileges.** Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: If you can connect to the instance using some other application on your machine, then chances are pretty good that you can fix this problem without needing anyone else. But in any case, I suspect the folks over at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found that by navigating to config -> Oracle and editing the file 'tnsnames.ora' the problem can be solved. The tnsnames file appears as follows:

```
connection_name =
   (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS_LIST =
       (ADDRESS= ... )
     )
     (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SERVICE_NAME= ...)
     )
)
```

By changing the first instance of `connection_name` to `connection_name.WORLD`, then typing

```
set ORACLE_HOME=
```

into the command line before executing the Python script, the above script now runs with no error.

Answer (score 0):

ORA-12557 is caused by problems with the `%ORACLE_HOME%` on Windows. That's the usual suggestion is to change the `PATH` setting.

> "I cannot do this since I don't have appropriate administer privileges."

In which case you don't have too many options. Perhaps you could navigate to the ORACLE_HOME directory and run your script from there. Otherwise look to see what other tools you have available: Oracle SQL Developer? TOAD? SQL*Plus?

Comment: Is it possible to specify - within the python script - where the Oracle home directory is and do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

I use ini-file to store DB connection parameters. Hope it helps.

```
self.mydsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(self.parser.get('oracle', 'db'),self.parser.get('oracle', 'port'),self.parser.get('oracle', 'service_name'))
        try:
            self.connpool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(user=self.parser.get('oracle', 'username'),password=self.parser.get('oracle', 'userpass'),dsn=self.mydsn,min=1,max=5,increment=1)
        except Exception as e:
            print e
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this python script for oracle csv export:

https://github.com/teopost/csv_exp